# Convert multi-line object to multiple objects using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a variable `$c`.

`$c` returns

```
apples
oranges
bananas
```

How can I make these separate objects?

```
$fruit = $C |  foreach { $_ -like 'oranges'}

if($fruit)
{
  write-host "Success" -ForegroundColor Green
}
else
{
  write-host "Failed" -ForegroundColor red
}
```

This doesnt work unless I use wildcards?

Im trying to get an exact match checking each line.

Any help is appreciated.  I'm stuck on this one.

Comment: What is C? A tring, array, hashtable?

Comment: $c = (invoke-webrequest -Uri "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1cMsdfasdfsj6ssdfsdfdsffHEj-fBb").content

I'm fetching contents of a text document from my googledrive

Comment: Please add the full command you use for getting `C$` in the question. Chances are you need to get `$C.Content | ConvertFrom-Json` to get an object that has your apples, bananas and other fruits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`-split` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split):

```
$multiLineString = @'
apples
oranges
bananas
'@

$arrayOfStrings = $multiLineString -split '\r?\n'
```

`\r?\n` will either match `CR LF`, otherwise `LF` on its own, so it'll work for both UNIX- and Windows-style line separators in the input string.

Comment: I'm fetching contents of a text document from my googledrive which has a simple list of fruits.
$c = (invoke-webrequest -Uri "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=documentIDhere").content 

When I check $c.length - Each letter seems to be an object?